# Hide QStandardItemModel row in data member function

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

How can I hide / exclude entire rows from a `QStandardItemModel` without removing them physically from the model?

Rational: I want to not display entities which are shown in another view. I already have a working highlight logic for that in the `data` function. Could I turn it(easily) in a "not display logic", so such rows are skipped?

```
    QVariant CMyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if (role != Qt::BackgroundRole) { return CModelBase::data(index, role); }
        .......

        if (model.hasSomeCondition())
        {
           static const QBrush b(Qt::green);
           return b;
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
```

Comment: How about using a [proxy model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html)?

Comment: using the proxy model to filter the original model?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So you don't modify the original model with logic that doesn't "belong to it".

Comment: Can I add / remove the proxy model at any time (ie by user interaction)

Comment: Yes. You just need to call `view->setModel()` to display proxy model or original model. Or you can just configure proxy model to not filter anything instead of removing it from the view.